# Flask-SocketIO + uWSGI. Emit with Mule worker

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, uwsgi, flask-socketio

Recently I'm implementing WebSocket support in my Flask app.

Setup looks as follow:
    1. Python 2.7
    2. Flask + Flask-SocketIo
    3. SocketIO (Client side)
    4. NGINX as proxy
    5. uWSGI 2.0.13 + it's WebSocket with Gevent (Monkey-patched)

I've manage to enable socket connection but I'm struggling on synchronization of emits between UWSGI Workers, single mule especially.

I have dedicated UWSGI mule to monit some stuff and reports the state every 30 secs, broadcasting it to connected clients. If I allow my task to run on any available worker (not only mule dedicated) emit reaches only to client that was previously server by exact same process e.g:
Client request was served by Worker #6 with (400 PID) and established Socket connection.
Later one mule task was served by very the same Worker so client received the Emit) If any other worker processed that task, emit is not cached by Client.

With single worker mode everything works fine, but that is obviously not acceptable solution.

Here is some tech details:
uwsgi.ini

```
[uwsgi]
#application's base folder
base = /home/ubuntu/application_test

#python module to import
app = manage
module = %(app)

home = %(base)/venv
virtualenv = %(base)/venv
pythonpath = %(base)

#socket file's location
socket = %(base)/application_test.sock

#permissions for the socket file
chmod-socket = 666

#the variable that holds a flask application inside the module imported at 
line #6
callable = app

#location of log files
logto = /var/log/uwsgi/%n.log

processes = 10

#WebSocket
http-websockets = true

gevent = 1000
enable-threads = true
die-on-therm = true

vacuum = true

mule=%(base)/application_test/uwsgi_mules/metrics_mule.py
```

Flask App

```
(...)
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app,message_queue='redis://')
(...)
```

Worker Emit Code

```
socket = SocketIO(message_queue='redis://')

def broad_cast_server_info(state, health):
    socket.emit('sys_state', health)
    socket.emit('system_snapshot', state)
```

Client Side

```
        socket.on('sys_state', function(data){
            (...)
            }
        });
```

If I use client side socket.emit with acknowledgment response, everything works fine.

When In mule I simply import socketio and call emit on it I face problem described above. However If I follow: 
https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#emitting-from-an-external-process

I'm getting an redis error every time mule runs its job.

> File "/home/ubuntu/application_test/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_socketio/**init**.py", line 365, in emit
>       skip_sid=skip_sid, callback=callback, **kwargs)
>     File "/home/ubuntu/application_test/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/socketio/server.py", line 228, in emit
>       **kwargs)
>     File "/home/ubuntu/application_test/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/socketio/pubsub_manager.py", line 66, in emit
>       'skip_sid': skip_sid, 'callback': callback})
>     File "/home/ubuntu/application_test/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/socketio/redis_manager.py", line 62, in _publish
>       return self.redis.publish(self.channel, pickle.dumps(data))
>     File "/home/ubuntu/application_test/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 2034, in publish
>       return self.execute_command('PUBLISH', channel, message)
>     File "/home/ubuntu/application_test/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 673, in execute_command
>       connection.send_command(*args)
>     File "/home/ubuntu/application_test/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 610, in send_command
>       self.send_packed_command(self.pack_command(*args))
>     File "/home/ubuntu/application_test/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 585, in send_packed_command
>       self.connect()
>     File "/home/ubuntu/application_test/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 489, in connect
>       raise ConnectionError(self._error_message(e))
>   redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error -2 connecting to redispass:6379. Name or service not known.

PIP FREEZE:

```
alabaster==0.7.9
amqp==2.1.1
aniso8601==1.2.0
appdirs==1.4.3
astroid==1.4.8
Babel==2.3.4
beautifulsoup4==4.5.1
certifi==2017.11.5
chardet==3.0.4
click==6.7
decorator==4.0.11
defusedxml==0.5.0
dict2xml==1.5
dicttoxml==1.7.4
docopt==0.6.2
enum-compat==0.0.2
enum34==1.1.6
eventlet==0.21.0
Flask==0.12
Flask-Login==0.4.0
Flask-RESTful==0.3.5
flask-restful-swagger-2==0.33
Flask-Script==2.0.5
Flask-SocketIO==2.9.2
flask-swagger-ui==0.0.3
Flask-WTF==0.14.2
gevent==1.2.2
greenlet==0.4.12
html5lib==1.0b8
hurry.filesize==0.9
hypchat==0.21
idna==2.6
infinity==1.4
intervals==0.8.0
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.9.5
jira==1.0.10
lazy-object-proxy==1.2.2
lxml==3.8.0
MarkupSafe==1.0
monotonic==1.4
oauthlib==2.0.2
olefile==0.44
ordereddict==1.1
packaging==16.8
pbr==3.0.1
pdfkit==0.6.1
Pillow==4.0.0
pql==0.4.3
psutil==5.4.1
py==1.4.34
pymongo==3.4.0
pyodbc==4.0.15
pyparsing==2.2.0
PyPDF2==1.26.0
pypyodbc==1.3.4
python-dateutil==2.6.0
python-engineio==2.0.1
python-memcached==1.58
python-socketio==1.8.3
pytz==2016.10
reportlab==3.4.0
requests==2.13.0
requests-oauthlib==0.8.0
requests-toolbelt==0.8.0
six==1.10.0
SQLAlchemy==1.1.6
SQLAlchemy-Utils==0.32.14
suds==0.4
urllib3==1.22
validators==0.11.3
vine==1.1.3
webencodings==0.5.1
Werkzeug==0.12
wrapt==1.10.10
WTForms==2.1
xmltodict==0.10.2
WTForms-Components==0.10.3
```

I've red about following cases:
- monkey-patch Gevent
- early-monkey-patch Gevent via uwsgi (suppose to work on uWSGI 2.1)
- add Redis queue

Is there any other method to make Flask-SocketIO works in sync with uWSGI workers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@shalbafzadeh gave me an amazing lead to follow. Here is the answer:

Flask-SocketIO in uWSGI multi worker pattern need both monkey-patchin AND some message queue mechanism as described in docs, like Redis. Making Redis working, resolved described problem. Here comes the Redis part:

**&TL;DN
Redis connection string was invalid. Redis doesn't support special chars in url, even encoded.**

Flask-SocketIO requires connection string to redis (code-behind uses redis.Redis.from_url() method). I've made clear mistake in posting a question, skipping fact that my redis is password protected so url in fact looks as follow:

> 'redis://[:RedIsPass#]@localhost:6379/1'

Yet error message is slightly misleading due to normalization of password string, and loading it as host. It removes special chars and lowercase everything. That brings me to error msg like:

> Error -2 connecting to redispass:6379. Name or service not known.

When I've fixed connection string to :

> 'redis://:RedIsPass#@localhost:6379/1'

I've encountered another issue, this time "Invalid IPV6" error.
It was caused by # in password. Sadly Redis lib doesn't have URL decode, so even replacing # with %23 won't fix the issue since %23 is passed as plain text and doesn't match the password. Had to change password on server. 
Regular password did the job.

Answer (score 1):

it seems to be a problem with redis
have you installed and started it ? 
run 
`redis-cli -h localhost -p 6379` 
to make sure flask-socketIO can connect to it

Comment: Ofc. Redis is up and running and fully accessible via native redis-py lib.

Comment: Somehow instead of connecting to redis://localhost:6379 socketio tries to connect to redispass:6379
change all occurrence of message_queue='redis://' to message_queue='redis://localhost:6379'